# Is there an in-universe explanation for the uniform change in Mirror, Mirror?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In *Mirror, Mirror*, when the landing party is ready to beam up they are in normal Starfleet uniforms, like this:[image: Landing party in Starfleet uniforms]

When they materialize on the *ISS Enterprise*, they are in mirror universe uniforms:

[image: Landing party in imperial uniforms]

Is any in-universe explanation why their uniforms were not transported with them ever provided?  And if not a canon in-universe explanation, was there ever an explanation provided by producers or other staff members?

Comment: I thought the ion storm caused those 4 to beam into the mirror universe and vise versa.  So the mirror guys appear on Enterprise in their uniforms from their universe.

Comment: @Jack B Nimble - I think the question is about why the transporter would differentiate their clothes and their bodies--if the transporter signal from the prime universe got displaced into the mirror universe and vice versa, why wouldn't the prime clothes be part of that signal and get displaced too? Maybe you could imagine transporters transport bodies at full resolution and separately transport clothes in some kind of lower-resolution way to save energy or computing power, and so the body transporter signal is different from the clothes signal, and maybe comes in a fraction of a second off.

Comment: good question - metaphysically, wonder if it is a mind transfer kind of thing - the prime crew is actually inhabiting the mirror bodies and vice versa because "transporter"

Comment: @NKCampbell: That's about the best answer I can think of.  We have some good researchers on this site, so I'm curious if anyone can find a quotation or something that might give some kind of authoritative answer.  If it is mind transfer, it'd be funny if one of them started wondering about scars on their mirror body that weren't there on their normal body.

Comment: @Tango - I don't have it, but I wonder if the Blish novelization digs any further into it? I'd also have to go back and watch the DS9 / ENT mirror episodes - perhaps there is more information there?

Comment: Perhaps the (unexplained, IIRC) universe-switching mechanism distinguishes between things that are "the same" (the crew's bodies) and things that are "different" (the uniforms).  Of course you'd then have to assume that the differences in the crew's experiences and personalities doesn't count.  (That kind of fits in with my headcanon about why the mirror universe has all the same people in the first place, but that's all way too wibbly-wobbly to post as an answer.)

Comment: I expect the answer would state something like:  the pattern buffer performed an error-correction filter when it recognized their uniforms were different.

Comment: Out of universe: for a chance to show off Nichelle Nichol's sick abs.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

Apparently they swapped uniforms with the people from the other universe. There wasn't the same level of commentary at the time during the Original Series, so lots of things were unexplained and then later fans started discussing them.

The behaviour of the transporter in *Mirror Mirror* is inconsistent with what we see in DS9.

In DS9, when this happens again, they don't swap uniforms. In fact, people from the Mirror Universe sneak various items onto Deep Space 9 in different episodes, and try to steal items from the station as well.